# RAID-5 read speed is very slow

Tags: ssd, raid5, intel, msi, nvme

I have windows 11 pro for workstation and use 2 RAID-5 volumes for storage (nvme group and ssd group). The read speed for the nvme group is around 2220 MB/s and the write speed is around 170 MB/s. SSD group counts as the same.
I tried 128kb, 64kb, 32kb and 16kb for stripe size, but the speed drops as the stripe size gets smaller.
I also tried hardware and software raid-5. Software raid-5 was slower.
Here are the data i have:

[Strip size:64kb hardware raid-5 for nvme(C drive):](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4GMfZ.png)

[Strip size:64kb hardware raid-5 for nvme(D drive)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1JqTK.png)

[Other benchmark app.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wx3xM.png)

[Other benchmark app.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wllkJ.png)

[Hd tune read result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2CSnI.png)

[Strip size:128kb hardware raid-5 for ssd(E drive):](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Te0Y1.png)

[Strip size:128kb hardware raid-5 for ssd(F drive):](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZCiyq.png)

[Non-raid ssd:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WgMuH.png)

***Update:***

I'm sorry for the confusion. I didn't realize that I sent the article before it was completed.

**Strip size:128kb,32kb and 16kb hardware raid-5 for nvme:**

I forgot to take a picture in my tests for this, but 16kb strip size had dropped to double digits.

**Strip size:64kb,32kb and 16kb hardware raid-5 for ssd:**

I forgot to take a picture in my tests for this, but 16kb strip size had dropped to single digits.

**Strip size:128kb software raid-5 for ssd:**

```
                      READ          WRITE
    SEQ1M (Q8T1)      50.68         96.88        MB/s
    SEQ1M (Q1T1)      54.08         25.13        MB/s
    RND4K (q32T1)     4.07          1.44         MB/s
    RND4K (Q1T1)      8.83          0.53         MB/s
```

**System information:**

Intel® Core™ i9-13900K Processor 36M Cache, up to 5.80 GHz

MSI MAG Z790 Tomahawk WiFi

4 x SNV2S/500G (Nvme)

ST2000NM0011 (SSD)

ST2000DM008-2UB102 (SSD)

TOSHIBA HDWD320 (SSD)

**Configurations:**

```
VMD controller                                = enabled
VMD Global Mapping                            = enabled
Intel Rapid Recovery Technology               = enabled
RRT volumes can span internal and eSATA dri   = enabled
ZPODD                                         = enabled
M.2_1 Max Link Speed                          = Gen4
PCIE_E1 Max Link Speed                        = Gen5
Extended Synch                                = enabled
Re-Size BAR Support                           = enabled
Native PCIE                                   = disabled
Native ASPM                                   = auto
```

All drivers updated latest version from msi.

```
Intel rapid storage technology product version : 19.0.1042.0
Intel rapid storage technology driver version  : 19.5.0.1037
```

The read speeds of both nvme and ssds are a bit slower than the manufacturer describes. And also the write speeds are extremely slow. I'm looking for a way to increase these speeds, especially the write speed. But I couldn't find it. I need your help to optimize these speeds.

Comment: I fail to see a short precise actionable question here. I also fail to see even an info about the hardware.

Comment: When stripe size is reduced, interrupt frequency is increased = takes longer.  128k vs  16k has 8 times less interrupts to deal with 128k stripe size vs 16k.  Welcome to SF.

Comment: Hardware Raid-5 will always be faster than Software Raid-5.  Again because with Software Raid-5, the OS has the duty to provide the management rather than depending on the Hardware management.  When possible allow Hardware managed services to reduce OS overhead.

Comment: I didn't realize I had sent the article before it was completed, @TomTom.

Comment: Thank you @Wilson Hauck . And I found the setting you mentioned. OS now controls raid volumes, but speeds are the same.

Comment: Which hardware RAID did you try? IRST is host RAID (=software RAID in BIOS). Try a decent hardware RAID controller with battery-backed write cache.

Comment: Is that even hardware raid, or a "pseudo" raid done by the drivers? Also, how high is the transfer rate on the slower M.2 (which is indicated as Gen 4, not 5)?

Comment: I'm a newbie about raid technology. I thought motherboard supported raid(created in bios) is hardware raid and windows supported raid(created in windows) is software raid. But i guess not.  @Zac67 I wanted to use this feature provided by the msi motherboard.

Comment: No - hardware RAID is when there's dedicated circuitry that handles striping, mirroring, parity calculation etc. independently from the operating system.

Comment: So can you give me some suggestions for hardware raid? When I search, there are pcie to nvme converters with raid feature (like https://www.amazon.com/ASUS-M-2-X16-V2-Threadripper/dp/B07NQBQB6Z/ref=sr_1_3?keywords=nvme+raid+controller+card&qid=1689373557&sprefix=raid+controller+card+nvme%2Caps%2C209&sr=8-3  or  https://www.amazon.com/PUSOKEI-Controller-Expansion-Individual-Indicator/dp/B0BG58941Y/ref=sr_1_19?keywords=nvme+raid+controller+card&qid=1689373557&sprefix=raid+controller+card+nvme%2Caps%2C209&sr=8-19). I'm not sure if this is the right hardware.

Comment: From rt clk on This PC My Computer, sel Properties, scroll to "Device specifications" and what is listed for Installed ram, System type?  scroll to "Windows specifications" and what is listed for Edition, Version, Installed on?   What is the planned database manager for this cpu?  MS Sql, MariaDB, MySQL, Drupal, Magento, WordPress?

Comment: This problem was solved after the new bios update.